# Ag grid multi-column groups

Tags: ag-grid

I was looking for an ability to add multiple grouping columns in ag-grid but could find only this 5 years old post https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/127 which is saying that this feature was planned to release but unfortunately hasn`t been. Maybe there is some other way to implement it?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmNKI.png)

Comment: I am also looking for this functionality. Have you found any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi group column as represented in [Ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-multiple-group-columns/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).